# Error encountered while processing command (domain=IXErrorDomain, code=2): Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID io.ionic.starter

Tags: ionic3

I’m getting the below error when running `ionic cordova run ios`

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-X, 11.2 simulator

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID io.ionic.starter
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=5):
The request to open "io.ionic.starter" failed.
(null) was unable to service the request.
io.ionic.starter: -1
logPath: /Users/josh/Apps/Illume/illume/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

Note: the log doesn’t seem to be there despite the last line of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Xcode fixed this issue.